# How to select only first 2 registers of a value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
Name           |   LoginDate
-------------------------------
Jane Doe        | 2020-01-01
John Smith      | 2020-01-01
Jane Doe        | 2020-01-02
John Smith      | 2020-01-02
John Smith      | 2020-01-03
John Smith      | 2020-01-04
```

And I want to select only the first 2 registers of a given name, so in the end I would have something like this:

```
Name           |   LoginDate
-------------------------------
Jane Doe        | 2020-01-01
John Smith      | 2020-01-01
Jane Doe        | 2020-01-02
John Smith      | 2020-01-02
```

Is there a way to make this Select? I am thinking of something similar to MIN(), but instead of the one smallest, I need the two smallest values of the dates for each Name.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by logindate) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

If all names have at least two rows, then this should be an efficient method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.logindate <= (select t2.logindate
                      from t t2
                      where t2.name = t.name
                      limit 1 offset 1
                     );
```

This can be modified to handle singleton names, but that adds a little complication.

Comment: Hello, Gordon! Thank you for your answer. I forgot to add that I am using Mysql 5.7, and it seems the ROW_NUMBER function is not available until Mysql 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple correlated sub query here

```
select *
    from table1 a
    where (
        select count(*)
        from table1
        where a.name = name
       and a.LoginDate > LoginDate
    ) < 2
order by a.name
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9533bc/9)